# Travis CI is failing for a Django project

Tags: django, travis-ci

Suddenly my Travis CI build is failing for Django project. The commit for which it was successful yesterday is failing now.

Any ideas on what might be going on? Here is the link to the failed Travis CI site: https://travis-ci.org/toladata/TolaActivity/jobs/242957738

The command "python manage.py test" works fine locally.

Comment: did you try specifying the exact version of `pyyaml` in your requirements

Comment: Just specified it as PyYAML==3.12 but it still fails with the exact same error as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by upgrading the `openpyxl` module from version 2.1.5 to 2.4.8. Apparently, the function `get_column_letter` has been relocated in `Openpyxl` version 2.4 from `openpyxl.cell` to `openpyxl.utils`